# I have a random dash that isn't part of the DOM, how can I remove it?

Tags: html, css

I have a random dash (-) [display on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yydzc.png) but can't work out where it is originating from to remove it.

On it's left is a  tag and on it's right is a  tag

```
<a class="w-inline-block price-list" href="http://www.smartcorp.com.au/PriceList.pdf" target="_blank">
    <img width="58" src="../images/Full_Product_List_Icon-2.svg">
    <div class="inline">DOWNLOAD<br />Full Price List</div>
</a>
```

If I set either the img or the div to `visibility: hidden;` [then it still shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap25a.png).

This makes me think that the dash is not part of either element and may possible be part of something further up, however, if I toggle `display: none;` on either of the elements the dash disappears (I'm out of links).

So I don't know what is causing this issue, it is not dirt on the monitor, it doesn't appear in the html nearby to the two tags. Using CSS with visibility makes it appear like it's not apart of the img or the div and using display it makes it appear as if it's part of both of them.

Comment: have you ever tried to inspect (inspect element) it?

Comment: it is how I was checking all of this out. In writing this I just found out the issue, the a tag wrapping around everything was trying to put an underline on the contents which was displaying the small dash in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag was trying to place an underline for the contents and it coming through as that small line. I solved the issue with `text-decoration: none;`